# Not able to click Tree view Nodes in Silverlight Application Automation using QTP 11.0

Tags: silverlight, testing, automation, treeview, qtp

I just started working on the silverlight application automation using QTP 11.0.

On the successful installation and with the required add-ins, I am able to identify the silverlight objects such as window(SlvWindow), Editbox(SlvEdit), Button(Slvbutton) and so on.

But in our application, in a particular page,we have a tree control(Slv tree view) view with nodes and we are not able to click the objects which are in slvtree and also wherever we spy in that page and nothing is getting recorded in QTP when we perform any operations in the tree control view.

Please let me know if any of you faced the above issue and the possible resolutions if available.

Note : Following are the add-ins and application information,

Add-Ins Used

1) Web
2) .NET
3) Activex
4) WPF->Silverlight

Thanks!